# How to append characters to a line of text in a file?

Tags: java, printing

I have the following text file:

```
2
4
8
16
```

I would like to append a `+` character onto the end of the third line, as such:

```
2
4
8+
16
```

How can this be accomplished through one of the Java printing classes (`PrintWriter`, `BufferedWriter`, etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot insert data into a file without overwriting the next character.

A common solution is to read the entire file line-by-line, examine each line to see if you wish to make modifications, and the write that line, modified or unmodified, to a temporary file.

Once you are done rewriting the file, close both files, and move the temporary file into place of the original file to complete the operation.

**Note:** This limitation is not specific to Java - that is a common property of many file system APIs in widespread use today. One would need to do the same thing in standard C, C++, C#, and many other programming languages.